# MYSQL: One query to copy assignemts for new item in many to many relation

Tags: mysql

Hi I have situation that users are assigned to projects in many to many relation. 
And each time i add new user i wish to copy for him existing assignments, in other
words to assign him to all projects, that other users are also assigned.
Currently i duplicate whole table and then reinsert it as follows, but was wondering
if that could be sorted in one query?

```
# tmp_assignments already exist and have same fields as assignment
truncate tmp_assignments;
INSERT tmp_assignments SELECT * FROM assignments;
# 38 is new user id
insert into assignments (project,user)
  select a.project,38
  from tmp_assignments as a group by project;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the problem with just doing:

```
insert into assignments (project, user) select project, 38 from assignments group by project
```

Comment: works perfectly. i guess i fought coping from same table into same will create some kind of infinite loop, silly me. cheers